# Modal window in nuxt architecture

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, modal-dialog, nuxt.js

Before I was working with Vue2JS and I used to creating modal as just component within App.vue root component for example:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
        <router-view></router-view>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
        <my-modal v-if="someBoolean"></my-modal>
    </div>
</template>
```

Now basing on some custom events or Vuex storage I was able to change `someBoolean` and trigger when I want modal to be visible.

Since in Nuxt we don't have such thing as root App.vue component I'm wondering how to achieve same as above but with Nuxt.

Of course I could use some package as bootstrap-vue but I don't really want to inject this big package just for that one purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write code in layouts/default.vue file and this file works on your defaults, work the code at where you used as a layout of your pages(generally almost everywhere.)

Different approach is use [portalvue](https://linusborg.github.io/portal-vue/#/) to render components whereever you want. Nice article [here](https://medium.com/@kenanyildiz90/https-medium-com-kenanyildiz90-vue-jste-portalvue-nedir-neden-kullanilir-36a45acc89f5) but in Turkish.

Comment: Kudos for sharing Turkish article as a response for English question.

Comment: I told him how he can do it. I would recommend a different approach and finally I would recommend a turkish article as there is no English source on the subject. So what is your problem with that?

Comment: Portal or rather teleport will be part of vue3.